# Скачивание нескольких файлов через WebClient

Tags: c#

Как узнать общий размер скачиваемых файлов перед загрузкой? Чтобы прогресс отобразить красиво. Сейчас получается только показать прогресс по одному.

Собственно реализация закачки взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992743)

Я пытался получить размер таким образом, но явно что то не то (размер получается меньше чем есть)

```
private void GetByteOf()
{
    while (FilesToGetSize.Any())
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string url = FilesToGetSize.Dequeue();
        Stream file = client.OpenRead(new Uri(url));
        WebHeaderCollection header = client.ResponseHeaders;
        double FileSize = double.Parse(header["Content-Length"]);
        TotalSize += FileSize;
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте послать HTTP HEAD для каждого файла перед загрузкой. Таким образом вы узнаете размеры всех файлов, не начиная их загружать.

---

Например, так:

```
var rq = WebRequest.Create(uri);
rq.Method = "HEAD";
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
var length = resp.ContentLength;
```

Comment: я новичок в этом деле. как можно это сделать?

Comment: @Виталий Леонов: дополнил ответ